# how to sample the current correct device attitude

Tags: ios, ipad, core-motion

I have to get the current device attitude. the ipad is in landscape right on a ipad holder and tilted somehow backward. the `self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude` on the first run does not deliver. the first value is equal when ipad is resting on the table? Am I missing something? how to get the current correct attitude?

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical toQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
        startattitude = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
        CMQuaternion quat = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
        double myRoll = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z)) ;
        double myPitch = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z));
        double myYaw = RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));
    }
}];
```

I need to get the correct attitude so in order later i can find out the difference between starting and new attitude.

after 34 update in handler block, it has the correct orientation value. how to find out that correct values is reached. debug output for yaw roll pitch:

```
2014-12-29 12:57:40.383 testApp myRoll: -68.0961
2014-12-29 12:57:40.383 testApp myPitch: 1.7463
2014-12-29 12:57:40.383 testApp myYaw: 2.2242
2014-12-29 12:57:40.386 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.386 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.386 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.386 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.387 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.387 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.387 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.387 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.388 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.388 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.388 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.389 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.390 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.390 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.390 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.390 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.390 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.391 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.391 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.391 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.391 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.391 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.392 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.392 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.392 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.393 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.393 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.393 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.393 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.393 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.394 testApp myRoll: -68.1005
2014-12-29 12:57:40.394 testApp myPitch: 1.7079
2014-12-29 12:57:40.394 testApp myYaw: 2.2592
2014-12-29 12:57:40.413 testApp myRoll: -68.1002
2014-12-29 12:57:40.418 testApp myPitch: 1.6904
2014-12-29 12:57:40.418 testApp myYaw: 2.2757
2014-12-29 12:57:40.419 testApp myRoll: -68.1011
2014-12-29 12:57:40.419 testApp myPitch: 1.6541
2014-12-29 12:57:40.419 testApp myYaw: 2.3094
2014-12-29 12:57:40.420 testApp myRoll: -68.1011
2014-12-29 12:57:40.420 testApp myPitch: 1.6541
2014-12-29 12:57:40.421 testApp myYaw: 2.3094
2014-12-29 12:57:40.429 testApp myRoll: -68.1038
2014-12-29 12:57:40.429 testApp myPitch: 1.6240
2014-12-29 12:57:40.431 testApp myYaw: 2.3363
2014-12-29 12:57:40.436 testApp myRoll: -68.1038
2014-12-29 12:57:40.440 testApp myPitch: 1.6240
2014-12-29 12:57:40.442 testApp myYaw: 2.3363
2014-12-29 12:57:40.444 testApp myRoll: -68.1038
2014-12-29 12:57:40.445 testApp myPitch: 1.6240
2014-12-29 12:57:40.457 testApp myYaw: 2.3363
2014-12-29 12:57:40.459 testApp myRoll: -68.1055
2014-12-29 12:57:40.460 testApp myPitch: 1.6077
2014-12-29 12:57:40.462 testApp myYaw: 2.3511
2014-12-29 12:57:40.463 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.465 testApp myPitch: 1.5822
2014-12-29 12:57:40.467 testApp myYaw: 2.3747
2014-12-29 12:57:40.472 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.474 testApp myPitch: 1.5822
2014-12-29 12:57:40.476 testApp myYaw: 2.3747
2014-12-29 12:57:40.478 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.478 testApp myPitch: 1.5822
2014-12-29 12:57:40.479 testApp myYaw: 2.3747
2014-12-29 12:57:40.480 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.481 testApp myPitch: 1.5822
2014-12-29 12:57:40.483 testApp myYaw: 2.3747
2014-12-29 12:57:40.486 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.487 testApp myPitch: 1.5668
2014-12-29 12:57:40.488 testApp myYaw: 2.3893
2014-12-29 12:57:40.489 testApp myRoll: -68.1061
2014-12-29 12:57:40.491 testApp myPitch: 1.5668
2014-12-29 12:57:40.492 testApp myYaw: 2.3893
2014-12-29 12:57:40.494 testApp myRoll: -68.1085
2014-12-29 12:57:40.495 testApp myPitch: 1.5357
2014-12-29 12:57:40.496 testApp myYaw: 2.4182
2014-12-29 12:57:40.497 testApp myRoll: -68.1085
2014-12-29 12:57:40.498 testApp myPitch: 1.5357
2014-12-29 12:57:40.499 testApp myYaw: 2.4182
2014-12-29 12:57:40.500 testApp myRoll: -68.1085
2014-12-29 12:57:40.501 testApp myPitch: 1.5357
2014-12-29 12:57:40.502 testApp myYaw: 2.4182
2014-12-29 12:57:40.515 testApp myRoll: -68.1125
2014-12-29 12:57:40.517 testApp myPitch: 1.5137
2014-12-29 12:57:40.518 testApp myYaw: 2.4381
2014-12-29 12:57:40.526 testApp myRoll: -68.1155
2014-12-29 12:57:40.526 testApp myPitch: 1.5031
2014-12-29 12:57:40.527 testApp myYaw: 2.4485
2014-12-29 12:57:40.547 testApp myRoll: -68.1160
2014-12-29 12:57:40.549 testApp myPitch: 1.4823
2014-12-29 12:57:40.550 testApp myYaw: 2.4678
2014-12-29 12:57:40.558 testApp myRoll: -111.3225
2014-12-29 12:57:40.558 testApp myPitch: 178.5306
2014-12-29 12:57:40.559 testApp myYaw: 5.6269
2014-12-29 12:57:40.579 testApp myRoll: -111.3233
2014-12-29 12:57:40.580 testApp myPitch: 178.5440
2014-12-29 12:57:40.580 testApp myYaw: 5.6146
2014-12-29 12:57:40.591 testApp myRoll: -111.3260
2014-12-29 12:57:40.591 testApp myPitch: 178.5605
2014-12-29 12:57:40.591 testApp myYaw: 5.5995
2014-12-29 12:57:40.612 testApp myRoll: -111.3311
2014-12-29 12:57:40.612 testApp myPitch: 178.5775
2014-12-29 12:57:40.613 testApp myYaw: 5.5849
2014-12-29 12:57:40.623 testApp myRoll: -111.3352
2014-12-29 12:57:40.623 testApp myPitch: 178.5856
2014-12-29 12:57:40.623 testApp myYaw: 5.5785
2014-12-29 12:57:40.644 testApp myRoll: -111.3378
2014-12-29 12:57:40.645 testApp myPitch: 178.6032
2014-12-29 12:57:40.645 testApp myYaw: 5.5633
2014-12-29 12:57:40.655 testApp myRoll: -111.3330
2014-12-29 12:57:40.655 testApp myPitch: 178.6188
2014-12-29 12:57:40.656 testApp myYaw: 5.5477
2014-12-29 12:57:40.676 testApp myRoll: -111.3342
2014-12-29 12:57:40.677 testApp myPitch: 178.6249
2014-12-29 12:57:40.677 testApp myYaw: 5.5421
2014-12-29 12:57:40.687 testApp myRoll: -111.3386
2014-12-29 12:57:40.688 testApp myPitch: 178.6378
2014-12-29 12:57:40.688 testApp myYaw: 5.5316
2014-12-29 12:57:40.709 testApp myRoll: -111.3422
2014-12-29 12:57:40.709 testApp myPitch: 178.6439
2014-12-29 12:57:40.709 testApp myYaw: 5.5273
```

edit: without reference it remains the same. I need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that without giving a reference it delivers almost correct values. the values contain noises which i have filtered with ±2 degree.

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
self.motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;

[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil)
    {
         startattitude = self.motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
    }
}];
```